# How to set Timestep in vtk-file(s) to visualize in Paraview

Tags: vtk, paraview

Sorry this might be quite a simple question but I'm new to this so I'll just ask straight away.

I want to visualize data in paraview, therefore I created a vtk file containing Structured Points with Point data= Vectors.
This works good for one timestep but now I want to append data or create other files for further time steps

I found a way to do so via .csv files (https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Data_formats#CSV_time_series )
but not with .vtk files

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: how do you "create a vtk file" ?

Comment: @Mathieu Westphal:  According to this User Guide:
https://www.vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf

Comment: fair engouh. afaik .vtk can be opened as file series in ParaView without any problem. See attached : 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4a893ab412ff919df2ecb7f6e138beaf20180606115943/b67688fe44c2b9ba8b9ae4906d217e9020180606115943/72c135
please note that ParaView can open other formats that natively supports timesteps.

Comment: I have answered this question in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69889294/13394817).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found an answer:

It is now possible to animate legacy VTK file series. ParaView recognizes file series named using certain patterns including:

fooN.vtk

foo_N.vtk

foo-N.vtk

foo.N.vtk 
...

Where N is an integer (with any number of leading zeros).

https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Animating_legacy_VTK_file_series