# How can I compose several xml-vtk files (vtu, vti) into one to get an animation?

Tags: visualization, vtk, paraview

I have a simulation which produces a bunch of `vtu` (also `pvtu`) and `vti` (also `pvti`) files which, as I understand, represent the configuration of points in one timestamp. But is there a way to group them into one close-to-vtk file to be able to visualize a simulation, which consists of many timestamps, in an app like paraview (but not only)?

Comment: see: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/69889294/13394817](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69889294/13394817)

Answer (score 1):

ParaView can natively open many files as a time series, see the [doc](https://docs.paraview.org/en/latest/UsersGuide/dataIngestion.html#opening-data-files-in-paraview).

If your file names contains a number, the ParaView "open file" dialog will collapse them under a dummy filename containing dots instead of number. Open it to open the whole series.

##### edit: conversion

To be close to the `vtk` format, you may use `.pvd` that is a ParaView format described [here](https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Data_formats#PVD_File_Format) or the `.series` from VTK (doc [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/blob/v5.5.0/Documentation/release/ParaView-5.5.0.md#json-based-new-meta-file-format-for-series-added) )

To read it with another software, well, you will need to check the supported file formats by the application you want to use. VTK can write several other formats, including Exodus, XDMF or CGNS for instance.

Comment: But is it possible to do that without using tools of paraview?

Comment: You can have a meta-file to descrive timesteps or use another fileformat. I updated my answer to add a conversion part